# Ubuntu 22.04 Unable to install MongoDB

Tags: apt, software-installation, 22.04, mongodb

OS: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS x86_64

I am trying to install MongoDB community edition from the official website. I was following the instructions but I am facing two problems.

The first:
When running `sudo apt-get update` I get this at the bottom,

```
W: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/focal/mongodb-org/5.0/Release.gpg: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

The second: When Running `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-mongos : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
 mongodb-org-server : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
 mongodb-org-shell : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use the upstream version (more difficult) instead of the Ubuntu version (much easier)?

Comment: You are trying to install a version built for 20.04.

Comment: Yes because i didn't find any mongoDB version for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, so I tried to install 20.04 instead because it's a bit newer. 
Will a new version of mongodb be released soon for Ubuntu 22.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the libssl version that is available on 22.04 is only version 3 https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=jammy-updates&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libssl which seems to be unsupported by MongoDB, in addition, the installation instructions do not list 22.04 as supported, it seems you'll have to use another version or use the docker image: https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo